# Getting ambiguous value in response for REST service on SOAPUI tool

Tags: soapui

```
{
   "application_type": "AEST",
   "catogory": "ROF",
   "app_number": "9.57390697575E7",
}
```

the app_number parameter should get me a integer value but im getting a ambiguous value .

Comment: If you're not expecting that result, the server is in error.. not soapui.

Comment: checked the same service from other tools ....there im getting the correct value

Comment: @karandevkar, what does it show in the raw tab? What other tools have you used to test and what is the response in that tool?

Comment: in raw getting the same response .app_number is a large integer value .I have used Postman and Talent API tester .There is works fine.